# New regular expression doesn't match even though based on one that does work

Tags: php, regex

I don't know much about regular expressions, but I have one that is working properly:

```
preg_match_all('!<span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">(.*?)<\/span>!', $result, $match);
```

Properly matches to:

```
<span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">                $9.00                </span>
```

And yet I just created another expression:

```
 preg_match_all('!<span class="a-size-medium olpCondition a-text-bold">(.*?)<\/span>!', $result, $match);
```

That is based on the last one, and it doesn't match the following data:

```
<span class="a-size-medium olpCondition a-text-bold">
        Used
            - Very Good
    </span>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: There is a newline in the second example...

Comment: @assylias Oh, I see. It does appear to work if I take out the new line. How would I account for this in the expression? I can't change the underlying HTML unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667369/php-preg-match-not-matching-past-line-breaks

Comment: Use the `s` modifier so that `.*` can match across newlines;